# Adding an array of objects to local storage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

tried saving an array of objects into localStorage and then getting it back.

for some reason in console the new arr is empty (history = [])
and in localStorage, savedgameHistory = [{},{}]

*SORRY! I didn't explain myself right, I need to save the array order. in order to use it in an UNDO button.

```
const img1 = document.getElementById("img1"); // img tag
const img2 = document.getElementById("img2"); // img tag

let arrOfObj = [img1, img2]

function saveGame(){
localStorage.setItem("savedgameHistory", JSON.stringify(arrOfObj));
window.location.href = "./TicTacToe.html";
}

function loadGame(){
 const history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedgameHistory"));
}
```

Comment: HTML Elements are not serializeable. Why are you trying to store the img tag in the localstorage?! BTW: The backslashes are usless.

Comment: Arrays are ordered by design. Its not clear what you try to archive.

Answer (score 0):

You don't save the image tag in the local storage, instead, you save a string, the string you want to save is the src attribute of the image, so you save it as follows:

```js
const img1 = document.getElementById("img1"); // img tag
const img2 = document.getElementById("img2"); // img tag

let arrOfObj = [img1.src, img2.src]

function saveGame() {
  localStorage.setItem("savedgamehistory", JSON.stringify(arrOfObj));
  window.location.href = "./TicTacToe.html";
}

function loadGame() {
  const history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedgameHistory"));
}
```

then, after you load it, you treat it as an src string, so you place it directly on your image tag in your html file, ex:

```html
<img id="img1" />
<img id="img2" />
```

```js
function loadGame() {
  const history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedgameHistory"));
  img1.src = history[0]  
  img2.src = history[1]
}
```

Comment: *SORRY! I didn't explain myself right, I need to save the array order. in order to use it in an UNDO button.

Comment: @Yoan, but arrays are ordered by default, objects which are not (or used not to be I should say)